# how to bind to a list of key value pairs

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF service that returns a `List<KeyValuePair<long, string>>` - I need to bind this to a `DisplayMemberPath` and the `SelectedValuePath`, anyone know how I might bind to the key and the value? *goink* I guess I have never run into this before...

Thanks

Comment: Opps - The question got messed up from HTML encoding or something... I am getting back a List of KeyValuePairs... And Yes, when I get a good answer I will mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Two things to clarify: Is this a WinForms or WPF control you're binding to, and what control is exposing those Path properties?

Comment: I assume the keys aren't unique thus you not using a `Dictionary<long,string>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi if anyone is wondering this was a two step process...

1) I converted the list to an observable collection

```
public ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<long, string>> Companies
{
  get;
  private set;
}
```

1.a) in the ctor I populated it like this...

```
 using (var client = new CompanyBusinessClient())
  {
    Companies = new ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<long, string>>(client.GetCompanyList(new List<long>() { 2 }));
  }
```

2) in the XAML I created a listbox

```
  <ListBox Height="24" Width="200" x:Name="ItemsListBox" Grid.Row="0"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Companies}"
        DisplayMemberPath="Value"
        SelectedValuePath="Key"
        SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Company}">
    </ListBox>
```

That actually worked, the idea was to create a dropdown but then my boss talked to some people and they decided they didn't need that ability on that view *shrug* whatever, If anyone ever finds themselves in a similar position maybe this will help.